# How to create OneToMany references between documents already inserted in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

It is the first time I am using MongoDB and I don't know how to create references (relationships in SQL) between documents which are already inserted in my database.

I have two collections: the first one is called Films, and its documents have information about films (title, a unique URL, description...). Here is an example of a document:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6272aa886441c51b18de7b23"
  },
  "type": "Film",
  "title": "Les 2 papas et la maman",
  "genres": "Comedia",
  "description": "Jérôme and Delphine want a child but Jerome is sterile. They then ask the best friend of Jerome, Salim, to be the donor for artificial insemination of the mother...",
  "platform": "Netflix"
  "film_url": "exampleurl.com"
}
```

Also, there is another collection called "Actors". Every document in the "Actors" collection has specific information about a certain Actor, the film in which he/she participates (title and a unique URL) and the character that he/she represents. A document of this collection could be the next one:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6272ac5b6441c51b18de9ee4"
  },
  "name": "Sophie Rundle",
  "film_title": "Peaky Blinders",
  "film_url": "exampleurl.com",
  "character": "Ada Shelby",
  "num_episodes": "36"
}
```

I want to create a OneToMany reference between the Collection Films and the collection Actors (a film has many actors, and one actor represents a character in a film), creating an array inside each Film document, which contains the ids of those actors who participate in a certain film. To do that, I have the unique field "film_url" in both collections and I have two CSV files with the data, so I could read and iterate over them to create the references, but it isn't a good idea in terms of efficiency, since each file has more than 10,000 lines.

Is there a simpler and more efficient way to create these references in MongoDB?

Comment: Nope there is no simpler way. You have to edit every object adding the id/s of the objects you want it to reference.

Comment: You can do this using `"$lookup"`.  Do you want to just retrieve the "actors" array with each film, or do you want update the "Films" collection with this array?

Comment: I want to update the "Films" collection to include the array of actors for each film document.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could possibly add and populate an `"actorIds"` array in the `Films` collection.  If your collections are large, I expect this will take some time since each film will need to get its actors.  Indexes will probably be useful.

Before using this, I would evaluate [MongoDB's warning about "output to the same collection that is being aggregated"](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#output-to-the-same-collection-that-is-being-aggregated).  Infinite loops are not fun, but I *doubt* that would be an issue with this pipeline.  You should make your own decision about using this - it's your responsibility (not mine!).  Expert analysis/opinions are welcome.

```js
db.Films.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Actors",
      "localField": "film_url",
      "foreignField": "film_url",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "actorIds"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "actorIds": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$actorIds",
          "in": "$$this._id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": "Films"
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hwLh6Zpehzs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution worked, but it took some time because my collections are very large. I don't know if Indexes would be useful in this situation since I need to execute the query between all the documents

Comment: @JesúsRoldánCadena I'm wondering if an index on `"film_url"` might speed the `"$lookup"`.  I don't really know though.

Comment: I have created an index for the field "film_url" (sorting and making it unique) and the performance has improved a lot. Thank you for your help! :)